# I am trying to deploy an app to Heroku with Django_tables2 and receiving "ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' "

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-tables2

I have been stuck on this for days now and it is driving me crazy. I have a Django app that runs perfectly until I try to render a Django_tables2 table into the template. It works perfectly when I run on localhost but for some reason when I try to migrate or deploy to Heroku I get the following logs:

```
(venv) home@Trevors-MacBook-Pro MHRH % heroku run python manage.py migrate
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ medicinehatregionalhospital... up, run.1733 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 19, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_tables2/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .tables import Table, TableBase, table_factory
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_tables2/tables.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import columns
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_tables2/columns/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import library, BoundColumn, BoundColumns, Column
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_tables2/columns/base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django_tables2.utils import (
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_tables2/utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist
ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)
```

I updated all site-packages to the most current version as most other sources have recommended but I still can't get it to work. Localhost works perfectly and when I take the table out of my project it works flawlessly as well. All help is appreciated.

Comment: `FieldDoesNotExist` was in `django.db.models.fields` [prior to Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/exceptions/#fielddoesnotexist), which is _ancient_. What version of Django are you using? What version of `django-tables2`?

Comment: django-tables2==2.3.3 and Django==3.1.4... It has me scratching my head because it works fine locally but it seems like the Heroku dependencies may be utilizing a different version for it to trigger that error.